# How to add external css/js files in vertx

Tags: java, vert.x

How do I add external CSS/Javascript files in Vertx?
I have managed to send index.html, which is displayed. This index.html has some external Javascript/CSS files, and the vertx is not loading the CSS/Javascript files in index.html.
The code is given below.

```
public void start() {
    vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(req -> {
            req.response()
                .putHeader("content-type", "text/html")
                .sendFile("index.html");
        }).listen(8080);
}
```

and in index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="someJsFile.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        Hello World
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is vertx 3

config router to serve static content

```
router.route().handler(StaticHandler.create());
```

my static files in folder `src/main/resources/webroot`

Answer (score 1):

Back in Vert.x 2 time there was simple example how to do this:

```
import org.vertx.java.core.Handler;
import org.vertx.java.core.http.HttpServerRequest;
import org.vertx.java.platform.Verticle;

public class Server extends Verticle {
  public void start() {
      vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(new Handler<HttpServerRequest>() {
          public void handle(HttpServerRequest req) {
              String file = req.path().equals("/") ? "index.html" : req.path();
              req.response().sendFile("webroot/" + file);
          }
      }).listen(8080);
  }
}
```

See here: http://vertx.io/vertx2/ (Java tab)

Mind the disclaimer ;)

> - In a real production web-server you would want to do some checking of the path to ensure files aren't served from outside the webroot!

Answer (score 0):

I am using vertx `4.3.7` and i wasn't able to make it work with above solutions.

I had to specify the entire path, like so:

```
router.route().handler(StaticHandler.create("src/main/resources/"));
```

And my css file is placed in `src/main/resources/css`